# Angular 2: event emitting between sibling component

Tags: angular, observable, eventemitter

In my Angular 2 project I want event communication between sibling component and I have read some articles ans follow some question on stackoverflow on this topic and now finally I am using **SERVICES EMITTING EVENTS USING RXJS** as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376854/delegation-eventemitter-or-observable-in-angular2/35568924#35568924) which is good solution.

But I have following situation.
This is my **AppComponent** html.

```
<section class="app content-area">
  <fds-header></fds-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</section>
```

I have three component **AuthComponent**, **HomeComponent** and **HeaderComponent**. First two component is rendering in outlet and last component has its own element/selector **fds-header**. So whatever component is rendered in outlet is sibling of **HeaderComponent**. In **HeaderComponent** there is a logout button and logout functionality is in **AuthComponent**. I am emitting event from **HeaderComponent** and catch in in **AuthComponent**. The problem is when user successfully login then he is redirected to **HomeComponent** and on **HomeComponent** when I refresh the page application is re-initialized and this time **AuthComponent** is not created so logout does not work because there is only one subscriber in **AuthComponent** which is not available. So my question is how can I handled this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While sign-in requires a component, you can achieve sign-out using a service call without the need for a component.

In such a scenario the subscriber will not be the `AuthComponent` but a `AuthService` which at the end of sign-out navigate you to login page again.